# How to list all urls stored in SQLite3 "History" Database of Google Chrome?

Tags: vbscript, foreach

In my case, after istalled [sqliteodbc](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/), is possible have access to SQLite3 "History" Database of Google Chrome and get the "urls" table,  my main goal here, is to list all urls stored in column "url", but on my implementation below, I'm catching only the first url visited.

[image]

So, how do for show ALL urls stored in column "url" from "urls" table?

```
Const LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA = &H1c&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

'Wscript.Echo objFolderItem.Path

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

Dim sCurDir
Dim sFina

For Each objItem in colItems
    'Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
    If InStr(1, objItem.Name, "Google") > 0 Then

      sCurDir =  objFolderItem.Path + "\" + objItem.Name + "\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
      sFina = "History"

      'Wscript.Echo sCurDir + sFina

      Exit For

    End If
Next

    Dim oCS     : oCS       = "Driver={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};Database=@FSPEC@;StepAPI=;Timeout="
    Dim oCNCT   : Set oCNCT = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" ) 

    Dim sSQL    : sSQL      = "SELECT * FROM urls"

    Dim oRS
    Dim oFld

    oCS = Replace( oCS, "@FSPEC@", sCurDir + sFina )
    oCNCT.Open oCS
    WScript.Echo "connected to", sCurDir + sFina

    Set oRS = oCNCT.Execute( sSQL )

    For Each oFld In oRS.Fields

    If InStr(1, oFld.Name, "url") > 0 Then

            WScript.Echo oFld.Value

            End If
        Next
        oRS.MoveNext

    oCNCT.Close
    Set oCNCT = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ADODB recordset has to be iterated through. In your code, instead, you iterate through the fields collection looking for `url` then grab the value from the FIRST record. Then you `oRS.MoveNext` to the second record... and exit.

Instead, after loading the `oRS` object:

```
Do While Not oRS.EOF
    WScript.Echo oRS.Fields("url").value
    oRS.MoveNext()
Loop
```

In the end, there's really no reason to iterate through the `Fields` collection of your `oRS` unless you are wanting to analyze the field types or field names or some other attribute of the individual fields. Instead you want to move through your recordset with `.moveNext`, `.moveFirst`, `.moveLast`, `.movePrevious`, or `.move()` [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677527(v=vs.85).aspx)