# How do a query in Google Chrome database using SQLite3.exe utilitary?

Tags: vbscript, sqlite

I'm needing do a query on Google Chrome database SQLite3 for capture of all urls visited [without use ODBC Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085378/how-to-list-all-urls-stored-in-sqlite3-history-database-of-google-chrome/36085833#36085833) or any other type of packet where is necessary your installation by final user.

Then I found that the way more near for this is using **SQLite3.exe** utilitary and SQLite3.dll (**C:\Windows\System32\sqlite3.dll**) in my opinion.

So I want know how I can list these urls based in code below?

```
Const LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA = &H1c&

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(LOCAL_APPLICATION_DATA)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

Dim sCurDir
Dim sFina

For Each objItem in colItems

    If InStr(1, objItem.Name, "Google") > 0 Then

      sCurDir =  objFolderItem.Path + "\" + objItem.Name + "\Chrome\User Data\Default\"
      sFina = "History"

      Exit For

    End If
Next

'Location of SQLite
strSQLlite = "sqlite3.exe"

strCommand = strSQLlite & " " & sCurDir + sFina & " " & "SELECT * FROM urls;"

Set objOutput = objShell.Exec (strCommand)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a shell to start the sqlite3.exe and to capture the output. As in:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Const cnHidden = 0
Const cbWait = True

Dim sCmd : sCmd = Join(Array( _
     "%comspec%" _
   , "/c" _
   , "sqlite3.exe" _
   , "-csv" _
   , qq("..\data\History") _
   , qq("SELECT id, url FROM urls LIMIT 5") _
   , ">.\urls.csv" _
))
WScript.Echo sCmd
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run sCmd, cnHidden, cbWait
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

output:

```
cscript 36346886.vbs
%comspec% /c sqlite3.exe -csv "..\data\History" "SELECT id, url FROM urls LIMIT 5" >.\urls.csv
Done

type urls.csv
25,https://de.add-ons.mozilla.com/de/firefox/bookmarks/
31,http://public.fh-wolfenbuettel.de/~hoeppnef/hanserSWE.html
33,http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/moin/OopDocbookWiki
34,http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/
35,http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/types-and-functions.html
```

I made some effort to isolate the components of a successful command line. So make sure you understand the whats and whys of each part before you start to adapt the demo code to your specs and circumstances.

Comment: if I try replace `">.\urls.csv"` by for example `sCurDir + "\file.csv"` the file don't is created. How solve it?